# Why did my website's layout fall apart?

Tags: html, css

So I'm doing a class on udemy on coding a PSD page mockup in CSS3 and HTML5. Everything was going well, and then when I started laying out the sidebar, my layout collapsed, with multiple objects appearing out of place. None of the `div`s are in the right places, content is scattered all over the page, colors aren't appearing correctly. In general, it seems broken, and I can't get it back to where it needs to be.

Demo JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4fT7R/

#### HTML:

```
<head>

    <title>Gyeahhhh and shit...</title>
    
    <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    
</head>

<body>

    <header>
    
        <div class="container clearfix">
        
            <a id="logo" href="/" title="Return to Home">
                <img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Logo"> 
            </a>
        
            <nav>
        
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="last-link"> <a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            
            </nav><!-- end nav -->
            
        </div><!-- end container -->
                
    
        <div id="hero">
        
            <div class="container clearfix">
            
                <div id="hero-title">
                
                    <h1>Really big title 2.0</h1>
                    <h2>Simple, yet engaging and descriptive subtitle</h2>
                
                    <div id="call-to-action">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-large">Primary call to action</a>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary action</a>
                    </div><!-- end call-to-action -->
                    
                </div><!-- end hero-title -->
                
                <img src="images/computer.png" alt="large desktop computer" id="hero-image">
            
            </div><!-- end container -->                    
                
                
        </div><!-- end hero -->       
    
    
    </header>

    
    <div id="content" class="container clearfix">
    
        
        <section id="column-content">
        
            <div id="lead-in">
    
                <h3>PSD to HTML5 &amp; CSS3</h3>
                <p class="lead">Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.
                Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
                
            </div><!-- end lead-in -->  
            
            <div class="column four">
            
                <img src="images/puppy.jpg" alt="puppy">
                <h4>A Cute Puppy</h4>
                <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>

            </div><!-- end column -->
            
            <div class="column four">
            
                <img src="images/crazy_dog.jpg" alt="puppy">
                <h4>Crazy Dog</h4>
                <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>

            </div><!-- end column -->
            
            <div class="column four last">
            
                <img src="images/husky.jpg" alt="A beautiful husky staring off into the distance">
                <h4>A Beautiful Husky</h4>
                <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>

            </div><!-- end column -->
            
            
            
        </section><!-- end column content -->
    
                
        <aside>
            
            <div class="widget">
            
                <h4>Latest News</h4>
                <h5>Dec 02 2013 </h5>
                <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
                    Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
            
            </div><!-- end widget -->
    
            <div class="widget second-widget">
            
                <h4>Follow Us</h4>
                    
                <div id="social-links"> 
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"> <img src="images/social_twitter.gif" alt="Follow us on Twitter"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"> <img src="images/social_facebook.gif" alt="Follow us on Facebook"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"> <img src="images/social_youtube.gif" alt="Follow us on YouTube"></a>
                </div>
                                
            </div><!-- end widget -->
    
        </aside><!--end aside -->
                    
    
    </div><!-- end CONTENT -->
    
    <div id="secondary-cta" class="container clearfix">
    
        <h4>Keep up to date with the latest news from our company</h4>
        
        <form>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" value="Sign up">
        </form>
    
    </div><!-- end secondary-cta -->
    
    
    
    <footer>
    
        <div id="footer" class="container clearfix">
        
            <p id="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2014 Gyeeahhh Enterprises</p>
        
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav><!-- end footer nav -->
            
        </div><!-- end footer -->
        
    </footer>
    
    
    

</body>
```

#### CSS:

```
/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    General Styles
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    
    html {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 20 px;
        color: #444444;
    }
    
/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Typography
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    
    h1, h2, h3 {
        font-weight: 300;
        margin: 0;
        line-height; 45px;
    }
    
    h4, h5, h6 {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 5px 0 5px 0 /* top-right-bottom-left */
    }
    
    h1 {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
    
    h2 {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    h3 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    h4 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 10px 0 /* if top/bottom and right/left are the same, then top/bottom - left/right */
    }

    h5 {
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }   
    
    p {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0; /* top-right-bottom-left */
    }
    
    p.lead {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 24px;
    }
    
/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Layout
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    
    .container {
        width: 940px;
        padding: 0 10px; /* actual width=960px */
        margin: 0 auto; /* sets containers to center content despite screen size */
        
    }
    
    header {
        background: #000; /* if a color code is six of the same number, you can use shorthand and only put the first 3 - i.e. #000 = #000000 */
    }
    
    #logo {
        display: block; /* there are two main types of elements...block and inline. block level elements
                        span the entire width of its container. inline elements are the width of the
                        element itself. images are block level, links are inline. */
        padding: 17px 0; /* you can select a specific margin i.e. top or left */
        float: left;
    }
    
    #hero {
        background: #00c0ff;
        color: #000;
    }
    
    #hero-title {
        width: 520px;
        padding: 60px 0;
        float: left;
    }
    
    #call-to-action {
        margin: 40px 0;
    }
    
    #hero-image {
        float: right;
        margin: 10px 0 -30px 0;
    }
    
    
    #lead-in {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    #content {
        padding: 100px 0;
    }
    
    #column-content {
        width: 700px;
        float: left;
    }
    
    
    /*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sidebar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
    
    aside {
        background: #444;
        width: 160px; /* 220px with 60px of left and right padding */
        color: #fff;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding: 30px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;  
    }
    
    aside .widget {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
    
    aside .second-widget {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    
    #social-links {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    
    
    
/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Navigation
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    
    /* nav ul is an example of selecting a parent and its child...refer to HTML */
    
    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: right;
    }
    
    nav ul li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left; /* css-tricks.com/all-about-floats for more */
    }

    header nav ul li a {
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 20px;
        border-left: solid 1px #333;
    }
    
    header nav ul li a:hover {
        background: #222;
    }
    
    header nav ul li a:active {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0 ,0, 0, 0.8) inset; /* for Safari/Chrome */
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0 ,0, 0, 0.8) inset; /* for Firefox */
                -box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0 ,0, 0, 0.8) inset; /* fallback */           
    }

    .last-link {
        border-right: solid 1px #333;
    }
    
    aside .widget h4 {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0 0 10px; /* top --> right and left --> bottom */
    }
    
    aside .socials a {
        position: relative;
    
    aside .socials a:hover {
        position: relative;
        top: -1px;
    }
/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Buttons
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
    .btn {
        width: auto;
        background: #0090bf;
        border: 1px solid #1e728c;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block; /* IE7 inline-block fix */
        zoom: 1;
        *display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        outline: none;
        padding: 10px 20px 11px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        
        /* button shadows */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
                box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
                
        /* CSS3 transitions */      
        -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
            -moz-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
                -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
                    transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
    }

    .btn:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #0086b2;
    }

    .btn:active {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
                box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .btn-large {
        padding: 20px 30px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 200;       
    }
    
    .btn-secondary {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .btn-secondary:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    .btn-secondary:active {
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
    }
    
    .btn-secondary, .btn-secondary:hover, .btn-secondary:active {
        background: none;
        border: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
        
    }





/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Global Styles
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */  
    
    
    .column {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    
    .four {
        width: 220px;
    }
    
    .last {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
    .clearfix {
        zoom: 1; /* for IE6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
    }
```

Comment: Though you cant post images, you can create a fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/ - this is too much to expect people will decrypt all this code from scratch by themselves ...

Comment: You are commenting out you `Global styles` could that be the problem?

Comment: The JSFiddle looks fine to me, what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: Edited the post to address the hold. How can we get the hold removed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## What's Going On

You mentioned that things all fell apart suddenly. Any one valid CSS rule is only going to affect certain things, so when multiple problems occur due to a single change, I tend to look first for typos: Missing brackets and Missing semi-colons.

Those are your culprit here. The main problem is that you are missing a closing bracket, which is causing much of the CSS to not be applied. There are also a few missing semi-colons which are causing some minor effects to not be applied on certain browsers.

## Code

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fT7R/2/)

#### Current:

```
aside .socials a {
    position: relative;

aside .socials a:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}
```

#### Correct: (Missing Closing Bracket)

```
aside .socials a {
    position: relative;
}

aside .socials a:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}
```

---

#### Current:

```
header nav ul li a:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0 ,0, 0, 0.8) inset; /* for Safari/Chrome */
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0 ,0, 0, 0.8) inset; /* for Firefox */
            -box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0 ,0, 0, 0.8) inset; /* fallback */
}
```

#### Correct: (`box-shadow` doesn't have a `-`)

```
header nav ul li a:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0 ,0, 0, 0.8) inset; /* for Safari/Chrome */
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0 ,0, 0, 0.8) inset; /* for Firefox */
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0 ,0, 0, 0.8) inset; /* fallback */
}
```

---

#### Current:

```
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
        -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
            transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
```

#### Correct:

```
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
            transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
```

---

## Summary

Any time everything goes haywire all at once, be suspicious for typos ... especially missing brackets.

Comment: yo...thank you sooo much brother...that fixed it instantly! I'll look for those from now on. Thanks for taking a minute to help me, man. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help! Since it did, could you mark it as the answer so that people in the future know that it works?

Comment: Will do, as soon as I figure out to do that. Thanks!